# Google Play Saved Games conflicts between DIFFERENT snapshots

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am attempting to use the newer Google Play Saved Games API (on Android, via Java).

It's possible I've misunderstood something, but when using multiple devices to save games I am getting conflicts reported for snapshots that have a *different* UniqueName, e.g. for a given Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult, calling:

```
getSnapshot().getMetaData().getUniqueName()
```

returns a valid name (but NOT the name of the conflicting snapshot that was saved!)

```
getConflictingSnapshot().getMetaData().getUniqueName()
```

returns null

Surely conflicts should only happen for the same file name ?

I'm using the recommended workflow for opening/resolving conflicts:

1) open

2) when conflict is reported, choose a snapshot based on modified date in the metadata

3) pass that to resolve

4) open it again

My snapshots were also saved using the normal workflow: open, update the data, commit and close.

Any ideas?   Have I fundamentally misunderstood something?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not very well - I added the file name into the snapshot's metadata/description, and checked that names matched.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONFLICT back for the wrong slot when I opened multiple snapshots at once. Opening each snapshot individually and then waiting for the result seemed to fix it.